# Возможно так расположить элементы с помощью display: inline-block?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, делаю макет как на изображении. Это карточки, нужно в таком порядке их расположить. Есть js библиотека masonry которая вроде так сможет, хочу попробовать сначала на css.

updated:

при скролле будут подргужаться еще карточки и аппендится в общий контейнер. У них чередуется порядок в шахматном порядке: 
высокая-две коротких-выскоая
две коротких-высокая-две-коротких

Comment: юзать грид либу для такой простой задачи не стоит. Дождись когда проснутся флекс-адепты, они все порешают.

Comment: Как я понимаю они не помещаются в одну строчку, поэтому нельзя

Comment: Зависит от контекста, подобная сетка используется для разных целей и если не понятно что там за контент, то не понятно как решать данную задачу, если критично, что бы все эти блоки лежали в одном родителе, то через `display: inline-block;` не решить (нужна вложенность). Больше подробностей нужно.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, обновил. Думаю самое просто и подходяще мне решение короткие карточки в контейнер помещать.
Затеял это, что бы упростить код шаблонизатора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С `inline-block` точно не получится, разве что вычислять отрицательные `margin-top` и прочие костыли.

Есть такой вариант с **flex** (минус - нужно вычислять высоту):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  font-size: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.item {
  width: 33.333%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519458524098-335b2a5747b2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=edd63ae6de5c3a3573b423bfcec62469&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527757728250-565ed17969c8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=91354952f33afa157965ee9f041d8cf5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475809913362-28a064062ccd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8744bee8594c81cac39bc702521b0acc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Вариант с `grid` (Минус- только для современных бразеров):

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


.grid {
  background-color: #e3fafc;
  border: 1px solid #99e9f2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0px, auto);
}



.grid > div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 4 / 8;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 4 / 6;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 6 / 8;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 4 / 8;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>2
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501707305551-9b2adda5e527?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0cf5887247e17503ce4e542d00d86b9d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>3
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527862399980-b92febc270b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1e171d0a6f3ff8c0d168e972c5009493&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>4
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508349937151-22b68b72d5b1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ab9aab3fb12c6b367439d2acea49898&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>5
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475809913362-28a064062ccd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8744bee8594c81cac39bc702521b0acc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>6
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513223848047-2456e15b4f7d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ebc05061b3e2a4fb76d2552cd94308a0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>7
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504433374832-4fcf45f40967?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=84d5ddcf804b74c6929073ebf76b7c95&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>8
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516476643801-3748856d17c1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ee7f14db4ae5132ad465b4e5c0fa21df&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Но лучше все-таки js.**

Comment: Так можно же в один блок 2 картинки и добавить `flex-direction: column`, если конечно не нужно по отдельности в каждый блок

Comment: @Arthur, именно если не нужно по отдельности) Если есть возможность группировки, то да, проще группировать, как например тут https://unsplash.com/